# Unable to update the Antd Form components based on the API Response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using ant design with react.

I am not able to update the Form.items values(2 Switch components and select option) based on the API response that I receive.

- Whenever I receive the `"preference_value": false,` in the API
  response then the corresponding Switch should be turned off.
- Whenever I receive the `"preferred_day_of_week": "Tuesday"` from the API, I
  want to set the select option value to be Tuesday.

The problem seems to be that component has two separate sources of truth for the state of the Switch component: the fields state and the eventBasedEmailPreference state.

So far I have tried to save API response in the variables and tried to change the values of the switches and select option component. But I was not able to make it happen.

I am able to get the Response from the API. however when I am trying to update the Switch components values inside the Form.items.

I have spent the last couple of weeks trying to find a solution but I could not find any.

API Response:

```
    {
        "id": 362,
        "user_id": 170,
        "notification_name": "Event Based Email",
        "preference_value": false,
        "preferred_day_of_week": null
    },
    {
        "id": 363,
        "user_id": 170,
        "notification_name": "Weekly Summary Email",
        "preference_value": false,
        "preferred_day_of_week": "Tuesday"
    }
]
```

This is the code for the component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button, Col, Menu, Row, Dropdown, Modal, Switch, Select, Form, FormInstance } from "antd";
import { LogoutOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import useRole from "../../hooks/useRole";
import apiAction from "../../api/action";
import useApi from "../../hooks/useApi";
import { MyContext } from "../../context/myContext";
import userNotificationPreference from "../../api/userNotificationPreference";
import AvatarComponent from "../../components/ui/avatar";
import { ReactComponent as EditProfileIcon } from "../../assets/images/EditProfileIcon.svg";
import { ReactComponent as NotificationIcon } from "../../assets/images/NotificationIcon.svg";
import { ReactComponent as LogoutIcon } from "../../assets/images/LogoutIcon.svg";

interface HeaderMenuProps {
  handleActionRequired: () => void;
  handleLogout: () => void;
  profilePic: any;
  actionCount: number;
}

interface UserParams {
  [key: string]: any;
}

const HeaderMenu: React.FC<HeaderMenuProps> = ({
  handleActionRequired,
  handleLogout,
  profilePic,
  actionCount = 12,
}) => {
  const getRequiredActionsCountAPI = useApi(apiAction.getRequiredActionsCount);
  const { isContractor } = useRole();
  const [requiredActionCount, setRequiredActionCount] = useState<number>(0);
  const [isDropdownVisible, setIsDropdownVisible] = useState(false);
  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [userNotificationData, setUserNotificationData] = useState<any>(null);
  const [fields, setFields] = useState<any>({
    eventBasedEmail: false,
    notification_name: "Weekly Summary Email",
    preference_value: false,
    preferred_day_of_week: undefined,
  });
  const [isPreferredDayOfWeekOn, setIsPreferredDayOfWeekOn] = useState(false);
  const [showCheckboxes, setShowCheckboxes] = useState(false);
  const [userParams, setUserParams] = useState<UserParams>({});

  const [eventBasedEmailPreference, setEventBasedEmailPreference] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [weeklySummaryEmailPreference, setWeeklySummaryEmailPreference] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [weeklyPreferred_day_of_week, setWeeklyPreferred_day_of_week] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);

  const { user } = useContext(MyContext);

  const getUserNotificationPreference = useApi(userNotificationPreference.getUserNotificationPreference);
  const putUserNotificationPreference = useApi(userNotificationPreference.putUserNotificationPreference);
  const formRef = React.createRef<FormInstance>();

  const handleMenuClick = ({ key }: { key: string }) => {
    if (key === "2") {
      setIsModalVisible(true);
      setIsDropdownVisible(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getRequiredActionsCount();
    // console.log(user.UserId);
    getUserNotificationPreference.request(Number(user.UserId)).then((res) => {
      // console.log("API response:", res.data);
      if (Array.isArray(res.data) && res.data.length > 0) {
        setUserNotificationData(res.data);
        const firstNotification = res.data[0];
        let eventBasedEmail = false;

        if (firstNotification.notification_name === "Event Based Email") {
          eventBasedEmail = true;
        } else if (firstNotification.notification_name === "") {
          eventBasedEmail = false;
        }
        let weeklySummaryEmail = false;

        if (res.data.length > 1) {
          const secondNotification = res.data[1];
          weeklySummaryEmail = secondNotification.notification_name === "Weekly Summary Email";
          setWeeklySummaryEmailPreference(secondNotification.preference_value); // Save weeklySummaryEmail preference value
          setWeeklyPreferred_day_of_week(secondNotification.preferred_day_of_week); // Save weekly preferred day of week
        }
        setEventBasedEmailPreference(firstNotification.preference_value); // Save eventBasedEmail preference value

        const newFields = {
          id: firstNotification.id,
          eventBasedEmail: eventBasedEmail,
          notification_name: weeklySummaryEmail,
          preference_value: firstNotification.preference_value,
          preferred_day_of_week: firstNotification.preferred_day_of_week,
        };

        // Update the fields state
        setFields(newFields);
        setIsPreferredDayOfWeekOn(firstNotification.preference_value === true);
        setShowCheckboxes(firstNotification.preference_value === true);
      }
    });
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the form values whenever fields state changes
    if (formRef.current) {
      formRef.current.setFieldsValue(fields);
    }
  }, [fields]);

  const getRequiredActionsCount = () => {
    getRequiredActionsCountAPI.request().then(({ data }) => {
      if (data && data.data) {
        setRequiredActionCount(data.data);
      }
    });
  };

  const handleModalClose = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(false);
  };

  const handleModalSave = async (values: any) => {
    const notifications = userNotificationData; // fetched from the initial API response

    const createNotificationParams = (
      notificationName: string,
      preferenceValue: boolean,
      id: number | undefined,
      userId: number
    ) => {
      return {
        id: id,
        user_id: userId,
        notification_name: notificationName,
        preference_value: preferenceValue,
      };
    };

    let eventBasedEmailParams = notifications.find(
      (notification: any) => notification.notification_name === "Event Based Email"
    );

    if (!eventBasedEmailParams) {
      // If the notification doesn't exist, use the id from the fields state
      eventBasedEmailParams = createNotificationParams(
        "Event Based Email",
        fields.eventBasedEmail,
        fields.id, // Get the ID from fields
        Number(user.UserId)
      );
    } else {
      eventBasedEmailParams = {
        ...eventBasedEmailParams,
        user_id: Number(user.UserId),
        preference_value: values.eventBasedEmail, // Updated preference_value based on the Switch state
      };

      // Ensure "preferred_day_of_week" is removed from the object
      delete eventBasedEmailParams.preferred_day_of_week;
    }

    let weeklySummaryEmailParams = notifications.find(
      (notification: any) => notification.notification_name === "Weekly Summary Email"
    );

    if (!weeklySummaryEmailParams) {
      // Here, the ID is set to undefined for a new object
      weeklySummaryEmailParams = createNotificationParams(
        "Weekly Summary Email",
        fields.notification_name,
        undefined,
        Number(user.UserId)
      );
    } else {
      weeklySummaryEmailParams = {
        ...weeklySummaryEmailParams,
        id: weeklySummaryEmailParams.id, // Here, the ID is preserved
        user_id: Number(user.UserId),
        preference_value: values.notification_name, // Use the Switch status as preference_value
        preferred_day_of_week: values.preferred_day_of_week,
      };
    }

    console.log("Form field values:", eventBasedEmailParams, weeklySummaryEmailParams);

    const payload = [];
    if (eventBasedEmailParams) payload.push(eventBasedEmailParams);
    if (weeklySummaryEmailParams) payload.push(weeklySummaryEmailParams);

    if (payload.length > 0) {
      const response = await putUserNotificationPreference.request(Number(user.UserId), payload);
      if (response.data) {
        console.log("API response:", response.data);
        // Handle the API response here
      }
    }
  };

  const handleSwitchChange = (checked: boolean) => {
    setIsPreferredDayOfWeekOn(checked);
    setShowCheckboxes(checked);
    setFields((prevFields: any) => ({
      ...prevFields,
      notification_name: checked,
    }));
  };

  const handleSaveChangesClick = () => {
    formRef.current?.submit();
  };

  // Extract preference values from API response
  useEffect(() => {
    if (userNotificationData && userNotificationData.length > 0) {
      setEventBasedEmailPreference(userNotificationData[0].preference_value);
      setWeeklySummaryEmailPreference(userNotificationData[1]?.preference_value || false);
      setWeeklyPreferred_day_of_week(userNotificationData[1]?.preferred_day_of_week || undefined);
    }
  }, [userNotificationData]);

  // Log preference values
  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log("Event Based Email Preference:", eventBasedEmailPreference);
    // console.log("Weekly Summary Email Preference:", weeklySummaryEmailPreference);
    // console.log("Weekly Preferred Day of Week:", weeklyPreferred_day_of_week);
  }, [eventBasedEmailPreference, weeklySummaryEmailPreference, weeklyPreferred_day_of_week]);

  return (
    <Row>
      <Col span={18}>
        {isContractor && (
          <Menu mode="horizontal" defaultSelectedKeys={["teamManagement"]}>
            <Menu.Item key="home">
              <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="teamManagement">
              <Link to="/">Team Management</Link>
            </Menu.Item>
          </Menu>
        )}
      </Col>
      <Col span={6}>
        {isContractor ? (
          <Row>
            <Col span={13}>
              <Button size="small" onClick={handleActionRequired}>
                Action Required ({requiredActionCount})
              </Button>
            </Col>
            <Col span={4}>
              <Dropdown
                overlay={
                  <Menu onClick={handleMenuClick}>
                    <Menu.Item key="1" icon={<EditProfileIcon />}>
                      Edit Profile
                    </Menu.Item>
                    <Menu.Item key="2" icon={<NotificationIcon />}>
                      Notification Settings
                    </Menu.Item>
                    <Menu.Item key="3" icon={<LogoutIcon />}>
                      Log Out
                    </Menu.Item>
                  </Menu>
                }
                open={isDropdownVisible}
                onOpenChange={setIsDropdownVisible}
                trigger={["click"]}
                placement="bottomRight"
              >
                <a href="#/" onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
                  <AvatarComponent size={20} pic={profilePic} />
                </a>
              </Dropdown>
              <Modal
                title={
                  <h3 style={{ fontSize: "24px", fontWeight: "normal", margin: "0", marginBottom: "0px" }}>
                    Notification Settings
                  </h3>
                }
                visible={isModalVisible}
                onCancel={handleModalClose}
                closable={false}
                footer={[
                  <Button key="cancel" onClick={handleModalClose}>
                    Cancel
                  </Button>,
                  <Button key="save" type="primary" onClick={handleSaveChangesClick} style={{ background: "#1B1464" }}>
                    Save Changes
                  </Button>,
                ]}
                style={{ paddingTop: "0" }}
                width={433}
              >
                <Form ref={formRef} onFinish={handleModalSave} initialValues={fields}>
                  <div style={{ marginBottom: "18px", display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
                    <div>
                      <p style={{ fontSize: "16px", margin: "0", marginTop: "0px" }}>Per Action Item</p>
                      <p style={{ fontSize: "12px", margin: "0", marginTop: "0px" }}>
                        Send an email notification for each individual
                      </p>
                      <p style={{ fontSize: "12px", margin: "0", marginTop: "0px" }}>action required.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div style={{ marginLeft: "auto", marginBottom: "25px" }}>
                      <Form.Item name="eventBasedEmail" valuePropName="checked" style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}>
                        <Switch
                          checked={eventBasedEmailPreference}
                          className={fields.eventBasedEmail ? "eventBasedEmail" : ""}
                          style={{ fontSize: "14px", transform: "scale(0.8)" }}
                          onChange={(checked) => {
                            setFields((prevFields: any) => ({
                              ...prevFields,
                              eventBasedEmail: checked,
                            }));
                          }}
                        />
                      </Form.Item>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div style={{ marginBottom: "0px", display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
                    <div>
                      <p style={{ fontSize: "16px", margin: "0", marginTop: "0px" }}>Weekly Report</p>
                      <p style={{ fontSize: "12px", margin: "0", marginTop: "0px" }}>
                        Send a weekly email of all new and outstanding
                      </p>
                      <p style={{ fontSize: "12px", margin: "0", marginTop: "0px" }}>action items.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div style={{ marginLeft: "auto", marginBottom: "25px" }}>
                      <Form.Item name="notification_name" valuePropName="checked" style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}>
                        <Switch
                          checked={weeklySummaryEmailPreference}
                          className={fields.notification_name ? "notification_name" : ""}
                          style={{ fontSize: "14px", transform: "scale(0.8)" }}
                          onChange={(checked) => {
                            handleSwitchChange(checked);
                          }}
                        />
                      </Form.Item>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div style={{ marginTop: "0px", marginLeft: "250px" }}>
                    <Form.Item name="preferred_day_of_week">
                      <Select placeholder="Select day" style={{ width: 150 }}>
                        <Select.Option value="Monday">Monday</Select.Option>
                        <Select.Option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</Select.Option>
                        <Select.Option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</Select.Option>
                        <Select.Option value="Thursday">Thursday</Select.Option>
                        <Select.Option value="Friday">Friday</Select.Option>
                      </Select>
                    </Form.Item>
                  </div>
                </Form>
              </Modal>
            </Col>
            <Col span={3}>
              <LogoutOutlined onClick={handleLogout} />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        ) : (
          <Menu
            mode="horizontal"
            style={{ position: "relative", justifyContent: "end", alignItems: "end", paddingRight: 20 }}
          >
            <Menu.Item key="1">
              <AvatarComponent size={20} pic={profilePic} />
            </Menu.Item>

            <Menu.Item key="2" onClick={handleLogout} icon={<LogoutOutlined />}>
              Log Out
            </Menu.Item>
          </Menu>
        )}
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
};

export default HeaderMenu;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `useForm` hook function to control your `Form` component in ant design.
One way to update the form values is to use the `setFieldsValue` method of the `Form` component. You can access this method by creating a `ref` to the `Form` component and calling it in the `useEffect` hook after you get the API response.

To learn more, see [ant design form doc](https://ant.design/components/form)